# How to compress image/byteArray from CameraX

Tags: android

I'm using the CameraX plugin which gives me a android.media.Image when I take a picture. 
Now I want to send the image over a webcall as a byteArray. I found a function that will create the byteArray for me:

```
private suspend fun createBytesFromImage(input: Image): ByteArray {
    return withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        val buffer = input.planes[0].buffer
        buffer.rewind()
        val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
        buffer.get(bytes)
        return@withContext bytes
    }
}
```

The image is pretty large and I want to compress/downscale it so a save some bandwidth. How do I do this with a android.media.Image or byteArray?

(I know I can make a bitmap from the byteArray, compress/downscale the bitmap and make a new byteArray out of it but this seems wrong. I'm looking for another way, if that's possible)

Answer (score 2):

Use instead `.setTargetResolution(Size(1080,1920))` on `ImageCapture.Builder`

To calculate file size according to resolution you can use [this tool](https://toolstud.io/photo/megapixel.php?compare=photo&calculate=compressed&width=1080&height=1920)

Comment: I used it in Preview.Builder() not the ImageCapture.Builder.